# How to find special Substrings in String array?

Tags: c#

I have many strings that are splited to many tokens(eg inArray). I need to find all special substrings(eg patterns)and replace them with "NN" in it. each substring/pattern has connected tokens but they may be separate tokens in each string array(eg inArray) and order is important.
For example if we have:

```
string[] inArray0={"this", "is", "simple", "text", "for", "example", "!" };
string[] inArray1= {"Can","you","help me","please","?","thank","you","very much","." };
string[]inArray2={"How","much","is","for","example","for","testing","your","solution","."};
string[] patterns = { "the", "that", "(for width)" ,"123", ".", "text", "for example", "help me","very much"};
```

desired output is:

```
inArray0={ "this", "is", "simple", "NN", "NN", "NN", "!" };
inArray1= { "Can", "you", "NN", "please", "?", "thank", "you", "NN", "NN" };
inArray2={"How","much","is", "NN", "NN", "for","testing","your","solution","NN"};
```

I used the Follwoing method but don't work correctly.

`changArray(string[] inArray,string[] patterns)`
`{`

`List<string> tmp = new List<string>();`
`foreach (string pattern in patterns)`
`{`
`tmp.Add(pattern);tmp.AddRange(pattern.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));}`
`var allPatterns = tmp.Distinct().ToList();`
`{`
`if (allPatterns.Contains(inArray[i]))`
`inArray[i] = "NN";`
`}`

How to change it or is there other solution?

Comment: Also, whats wrong with the answers in your previous questions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think all responses in my previous question don't response to my problem and I didn't find a good solution.so I change my question in other way!

Comment: please if you don't know how to solve a problem, don't remove problem!

Answer (score 0):

This would work, but you will need to do it for each array.

```
foreach (string s in array0.Where(w => patterns.Contains(w)))
{
    S = "NN";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped @JustSomeDude's code into a method which you can call for every input array.

```
internal void YourDesiredMethodName (string[] input)
{
    foreach (string s in input.Where(w => patterns.Contains(w)))
    {
        s="";
        for(i=0;i<s.Split(' ').Count();i++)
        {
            if(i+1==s.Split(' ').Count())
                s += "NN";
            else 
                s += "NN ";
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
YourDesiredMethodName(inArray0);
YourDesiredMethodName(inArray1);
YourDesiredMethodName(inArray2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but these codes don't work correctly for inArray0 or inArray2 examples

Comment: @K.Ros, I did not notice that you want to put "NN" for every word in patters instead of whole pattern member. İ edited the code accordingly.

Comment: 's' is a iteration variable  and can not assign to it. although  With edition  codes don't seem we get expected output for input arrays.